# network slowness troubleshoot

Tags: routing, juniper-srx, latency, wan-optimizer

I want some suggestion regarding our network issue:

From our office location to our DC ==> it's ~270msc(office and DC lies in different countries). As, you can already see here latency is the major concern for us. At working hours i've complains network is too slow while download/upload of files(even small size files as well).

Network wise:  cisco routers in office, we've 100Mbps internet(ipsec-BGP) ===> connection towards our DC.

Earlier, i've did some theoretical calculation of throughput = ~2.5Mbps what i got out of 100Mpbs pipe.

Proposals to solve issue:

1) Increase the bandwidth upto 1Gpbs, will that help for such long distance latency?

2) Replacing cisco routers in location with juniper srx(in remote office), not sure how it's gonna help but it's point.

3) Using WAN-Optimizer(im totally new to this) anyway will this help?

I would like to simulate high latency(as of ~270msc) in my lab, this way i can be sure if replacing cisco with juniper may be any help. In, order to do so is there any such commands to simulate latency between devices in same lab(although their latency is ~10msc, i want to those devices to see next hop as ~270msc)

All suggestions are welcome :)

Thanks & Regards,

Madhu

Comment: The latency is going to be in the Internet. There really is not much you can do about the Internet latency (with such a large increase in Internet traffic due to the current pandemic). You will need to discuss it with your ISP, but it may be a problem in another ISP to which it connects.

Comment: This may be off-topic, but considering the high latency and the cost and drawbacks of WAN accelerators (esp. limitations for secure authentication and encryption), you should seriously look at installing a local file server in the office. There are many solutions for replicating files in near real-time between locations, some even for free.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Option 3 is your only real choice.

You are limited by physics.  As you probably know, you are running into delay-bandwidth product limitations, so Option 1 --increasing your connection speed won't help.

Option 2 is great news for Juniper, but it will make absolutely no difference in performance.

You might consider adjusting the maximum TCP window size on the computers in your office, but option 3 may be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already accounted for MTU issues?

Often, an IPSEC or other tunnel over the public Internet will result in a path MTU of e.g. ~1420 bytes to destinations across the tunnel.  If your hosts are all configured for 1500 bytes MTU they can usually work out the lower path MTU in the absence of ICMP filtering, but it's also frequent that folks block the necessary ICMP fragmentation-needed messages required for Path MTU Detection to function correctly.  The upshot is worse performance all around.

The work-around typically involves configuring a feature such as TCP MSS *adjusting* or *clamping* (terminology differs) which changes the advertised MSS during the TCP handshake process so it won't exceed the tunnel MTU.

If you don't know that you've already done this, chances are you haven't!  It may be an easy fix to significantly boost TCP performance.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost is to  verify  bandwidth utilisation   on ISP. Internet link . And futher look for any packet drop in your entire end to end infrastructure or any congestion in network and even verify CPU ,RAM and disk  resource utilisation in network devices like firewall, routers and switches connected in your topology .